# sql trigger two tables not empty

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER bookAvailDelete after delete on Auction
for each row
Begin
if (Select count(OLD.isbn) from Auction a > 0)
update Book b
set available =false
where OLD.isbn = isbn
;
```

I have two tables, Auction and Book. Auction has isbn key that references Book isbn primary key. Many auctions can point to the same book so I want this trigger to check on every auction delete, to see if it was the last auction of that book isbn. If it is, then it sets the "available" key in Book to false.

Comment: so what is the error you receive ?

Comment: something with my syntax is wrong I think. Especially with the Auction a

Comment: I agree, but what is the error message ? Have you tried to do it ?

Comment: If..then..endif

Answer (score 0):

Please compile and test below. Use a variable for the count and put end if at the end too.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER bookAvailDelete after delete on Auction
for each row
Begin
DECLARE updatecount INT;
set updatecount = ( Select count(*) from Auction a where a.isbn = OLD.isbn);
if updatecount > 0 then
update Book b
set b.available =false
where b.isbn = OLD.isbn;
end if;
End;//
```

Comment: Don't forget to take `>0` off the `set updatecount` line.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, unless there were performance reasons, you'd just calculate this on the fly (instead of storing it) with queries like:

```
SELECT b.*
   , EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Auction a WHERE a.isbn = b.isbn) AS available
FROM Book b
```

or (my preferred format):

```
SELECT b.*, (a.isbn IS NOT NULL) AS available
FROM Book b
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT isbn FROM Auction) AS a ON b.isbn = a.isbn
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming available is int:

```
drop trigger bookAvailDelete;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER bookAvailDelete after delete on Auction
    for each row begin
        if NOT EXISTS(Select * from Auction where isbn = old.isbn)
        then
            update Book b set b.available = 0 where b.isbn = old.isbn;
        end if; 
    end;
```